# If 6 high school teams play each other once in a division, what is the probability that one team has a perfect 5-0 season?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I tried to use inclusion exclusion, and got something close, but not quite right. I am also assuming each team is as likely to lose as to win.

For the event $A_i$ being the event that team $i$ has a perfect season, with each event having $P(A_i)=(1/2)^5=\frac{1}{32}$, by inclusion exclusion
$$
P(\cup_{1}^6 A_i)=6\frac{1}{32}-{6\choose 2}\frac{1}{32^2}+{6\choose 3}\frac{1}{32^3}-{6\choose 4}\frac{1}{32^4}+6\frac{1}{32^5}-\frac{1}{32^6}
$$
The correct answer in the book is 5/32. By messing around on wolfram alpha, it seems that if I cut off the final term, which represents the impossible event that all 6 teams have perfect seasons, I get to within .01 of the answer. But why cut off this term? It also isn't possible to have 5 teams have perfect seasons? Also, how in the world did they get such a nice simple fraction?

Thanks!

Comment: There cannot be more than one

Comment: Odd, the answer should be $\frac{6}{32}$...

Comment: Remember that $P(A_1\cap A_2)= P(A_1)\cdot P(A_2)$ is true **only** when the events are independent.  In general $P(A_1\cap A_2)=P(A_1)\cdot P(A_2\mid A_1)$, but as mentioned it cannot be the case that multiple teams have a perfect season simultaneously.  (Suppose two teams both have a perfect season, then in the single game they played against eachother they both were the winner: contradiction)

Comment: @JoeyZou the back of the back claims 5/32.

Comment: @JMoravitz I noticed this, but I guess I don't really understand inclusion exclusion very well. Or at least got confused between when you are allowed to overcount and correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outline**

The key to this problem is first realizing that if one team has a perfect $5-0$ season, then no other team has a perfect $5-0$ season..  The probability of a particular team having a perfect season is winning all the $5$ matches, i.e. $\frac{1}{32}$. This can be any **one** of the teams, so the required probability is $\color{blue}{\frac{6}{32}}$

Comment: oy ok. So with inclusion exclusion, you "expand" until you reach an impossible event?

Comment: Yes, You could do it carefully, but it does get complicated, because of handling the impossibilities.

Comment: But there are six teams, not five, so shouldn't it be $6/32$?

Comment: the book is wrong! thank you

Answer (score 5):

There are, in the tournament, $2^{15}$ possible combinations of game outcomes, each of which is equally likely.

Of these $2^{15}$ tournament results, how many have one team at five wins?
You can choose the team ($6$ ways) and having done that, five results are forced, and the remaining ten results can be any combinations, you don't care about them.

So the answer is 
$$
\frac{6\cdot 2^{10}}{2^{15}} = \frac{6}{32}
$$

The correct answer in the book is using a definition of "correct" with which I was previously unfamiliar.

Comment: it's defined as "I trust the book more than myself"

Comment: I really like this answer, combinatorics makes it way more intuitive. Thank you!

Comment: Upvoting your answer. Nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

The implicit assumption seems to be that all teams are equally good so that each outcome of a game is equally likely. If the sport is soccer and one team is the Brazilian National team while the other 5 teams are local high schools, the record 5-0 is all but certain.

The "correct" answer therefore will depend on the ex ante distribution of ability within the division. (Though I doubt the textbook was expecting to proceed that way.)